# php5-fpm master process crashing

Tags: ubuntu, php

I have a problem with my PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4 (fpm-fcgi).
After a while the master process is silently crashing (nothing in syslog / php5-fpm log / nginx log).
Only thing I found was in upstart/php5-fpm (after master process was crashed)

```
ERROR: pid 4578, fpm_sockets_new_listening_socket(), line 185: An another FPM instance seems to already listen on /var/run/php5-fpm.sock
```

It is not possible to service php5-fpm restart, because several children live on. So is upstart not respawning the master process.

Does anyone know why this happens?
Thanks!